# What happens if permissions on the root directory ( / ) are set to 777?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

i.e., `sudo chmod /`, not `sudo chmod -r /`.

What could an attacker access? Is this okay for  a personal machine?

Comment: Mostly answered in this ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive

Won't mark it as duplicate (because your POV is user-based) but won't upvote either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An attacker (unprivileged user) would be able to create new directories and files in the root directory and to **rename** any existing directory in `/` (for example to a random value effectively rendering the machine unusable).

Combined it allows unprivileged users to **replace** existing directories with their own content. Think `/bin`. First:

```
sudo chmod 777 /
```

Now the attacker (unprivileged user) part:

```
cp -r /bin /newbin
echo "echo boo running my own code as 'whoami'" > /newbin/ls
chmod +x /newbin/ls
mv /bin /oldbin
/oldbin/mv /newbin /bin
```

Now check this:

```
sudo -i
ls
```

It is effectively giving an attacker a simple way to own the machine.

Comment: It's my understanding that if `/` has 777 permissions, then unprivileged users can make new directories and delete empty directories, but they can't add files to or delete files from protected subdirectories like `/bin`.

Comment: @Jamie no one needs to add files to/from other directories, they can just replace the whole branch at the root; try commands I added to the answer

Comment: @Jamie: Your understanding misses the fact that renaming `/bin` to `/random-bin` and creating your own `/bin` is as good as removing it.

Comment: @Jamie - Good one.  You are correct.  That you can rename a directory you don't own surprises me a bit !  I learnt something today.

Comment: @davidgo: Part of that is just the way *nix permissions work, renaming a directory is effectively a "write" operation on the parent directory - which in this case is chmod 777'd

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Sorry, what do you mean by "part of that"? I guess that's a complete explanation.

Comment: @davidgo: Well, permissions on the / folder are a special case and my understanding of it isn't 100%

Comment: I updated the "hack", on fedora21 and RHEL7 `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` so copying it only copies the symlink.  But more importantly after moving `/bin` to `/oldbin` simply typing `mv` will no longer work. There are some other gotchas not yet addressed but we don't want to make it too easy for any blackhat that comes along.

Comment: @Bram you are right, I mistakenly deleted the path to `mv` in one of my edits